# Open Google Play Store for specific country

Tags: google-sites

I can browse to Google's Play Store in my desktop browser. How can I open the Play Store's version for a specific country like Swiss or France?
Google opens per default always the German Play Store (since I'm in Germany).
But I want to check something in a different country's store.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting a language tag at the end of the play store URL, like so:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=fr

This should give you the French version of the store, for example.  *This might only change the menu language (since I am not in France I cannot verify).*  This may not include everything you would see in the other country, especially since some apps are restricted by country due to licensing or security regulations.

The only sure way to fool Google into thinking you are in another country would be to use a VPN with servers based in that country.  Be aware that since VPNs like this are often used to anonymize illegal behavior, you may find that IP has been blocked or otherwise restricted from certain sites.